# how to update multiple user controls in same window WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a scenario that i am having four user controls in a window(like address, Skills, Personal info and General info each user control is having their own controls like textbox labels etc....) each user control having their own View Model
ex: General Info Control having A combo box which has list of persons and a text box Age, and text box Gender
Address is having 3 text boxes Street, Area, City
Skills control having 2 Text boxes Soft Skills and Tech Skills

so when user selects a particular person from the combo box then it has to update all the user controls with that particular person data

**Main Window**

```
<Window x:Class="CTSWpfApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:View="clr-namespace:CTSWpfApplication.View"
    xmlns:localViewModel="clr-namespace:CTSWpfApplication.ViewModel"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="1000">

<Window.Resources>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type localViewModel:PersonViewModel}">
    <View:PersonVorw/>
</DataTemplate>
 </Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <View:PersonVorw Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding PersonViewModel}"/>

    <View:AddressView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <View:SkillsView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <View:PersonalInfoView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

**User Control PersonGeneralInfo(View)**

```
<UserControl x:Class="CTSWpfApplication.View.PersonVorw"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500">
<Grid DataContext="{Binding PersonGenModel}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Height="25" Width="150" Grid.Column="1" Name="NameSelection" ItemsSource="{Binding ListFirstName}" SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value"  SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}">

    </ComboBox>
    <Label Height="25" Width="100" Content="First Name" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Label Height="25" Width="100" Content="Middle Name" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Label Height="25" Width="100" Content="Last Name" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <TextBox Height="25" Width="120" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Name="TxTFirstName" Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
    <TextBox Height="25" Width="120" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="TxTMiddleName" Text="{Binding MiddleName}"/>
    <TextBox Height="25" Width="120" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Name="TxTLastName" Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
    <Label Height="25" Width="100" Content="Age" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Label Height="25" Width="100" Content="Gender" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <TextBox Height="25" Width="120" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Name="TxTAge" Text="{Binding Age}"/>
    <TextBox Height="25" Width="120" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Name="TxTGender" Text="{Binding Gender}"/>
    <Button Name="BtNPerson" Height="25" Width="100" Content="Clenter code hereick to Add" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" />
</Grid>
```

can any one Help me on to achieve this in the best way 
Please excuse me if you fine any mistakes in my post
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will have to notify other ViewModels when change occurs. This [article](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.in/2009/05/mvvm-communication-among-viewmodels.html) explains the patterns that can be followed to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a MainViewModel that creates your other ViewModels.

1. Create a property in each of you ViewModels called SelectedComboBoxItem.
2. Bind your ComboBox's SelectedItem in the MainViewModel to a command that sets 
   the SelectedComboBoxItem of each of the other ViewModels.

To be honest I don't know if it will work, but make sure to have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented in all of the ViewModels and their properties.

Example:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private YourInfoItem _selectedComboBoxItem;

    private ViewModel1 SkillsInfoVM = new ViewModel1();
    private ViewModel2 PersonalInfoVM = new ViewModel2();
    private ViewModel3 GeneralInfoVM = new ViewModel3();

    public YourInfoItem selectedComboBoxItem 
    {
        get {return _selectedComboBoxItem; }

        set 
        {
            _selectedComboBoxItem = value;
            PropertyChanged(nameof(selectedComboBoxItem));
        }
    }


    public MainViewModel()
    {            
        SelectedComboBoxItemChanged = new RelayCommand(SetSelectedComboBoxItem);
    }


    public ICommand SelectedComboBoxItemChanged { get; private set; }

    public void SetSelectedComboBoxItem()
    {
        SkillsInfoVM.selectedComboBoxItem = this.selectedComboBoxItem;
        PersonalInfoVM.selectedComboBoxItem = this.selectedComboBoxItem;
        GeneralInfoVM.selectedComboBoxItem = this.selectedComboBoxItem;
    }
}
```

In the end you just bind the SelectedComboBoxItem to your TextBoxes in the XAML code e.g:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedComboBoxItem.FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=OnPropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

and so on.
This does require you to have an object that contains all the information you want to show, you can do that by creating a class containing all the info, similar to this:

```
public class Info
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public string Address;
    ...     
}
```